# Using javax.sound.sampled with openjdk-7 on Raspi

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, java

I'm having big problems getting good sound out of my Raspi using Java.

I want to write an little AirPlay Client to a media server I wrote in Java. I started with using the Player Class from javazoom (http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/package-summary.html). Which gave me a not really choppy but somehow distorted and slower than normal playback of an mp3 file I streamed over to the Raspi.

My first idea was, that maybe the decoding of an mp3 was a bit too much for the Raspi, especially since overclocking helped a little.
So now I'm converting the mp3 to a wav file on the server and then stream it to the Raspi playing it with the javax.sound.sampled.* stuff. Yet, no improvement :|

Has anybody some experience with playing soundFiles from Java on an Raspi? Any advice helps!

Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try using JavaFX instead. It is way better than support for media on the standard JDK. Besides, you are already using Java 7, so migrating will be easy. Here is how:

```
Media media = new Media(Utils.findURI(baseDirName, soundFileName).toString());
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(1);
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the implementation of sound in OpenJDK has lots of bugs. One of them is that it abuses the sound system and monopolizes it. So on Linux you have better chances to get things working if you do as above.

Comment: Hm, the only problem is, that the Media Constructor only takes URIs. However, my media is coming from the InputStream of an Socket...

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you are right. The easiest solution that comes to mind is not to use stream but to save chunks of data on disk and then play it. But that would be an ugly hack.

Comment: The documentation says it supports HTTP, but not sure if it will simply download a file and play it, instead of a stream.

Comment: Yap, doesn't seem to do the trick... Thanks, though! If I'm going to have to save the stream again as a file, I would make it really ugly right away and go for a system call with "aplay file.wav" ;)

Comment: Too bad... I wonder whether Oracle is really serious about JavaFX. They are never going to beat Flash with such lack of basic features. The most they did was adding support for FLV, AFAIK.

If you are going to the Runtime.exec() way, then why not an mplayer playing a stream instead of aplay? You can keep the mplayer process running and manage it through Java.